# paste unix variables from loop into single file

Tags: linux, while-loop, paste

Is it possible to paste consecutive output from a loop into a single file?

something like

```
    cat filelist | while read line; do var=$(cat $line | cut -f1,6) ; paste < (echo "$var") >> outfile ; done
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: open each file in a list, take the first column and append it as a new column in an output file.

Comment: The way you're saying it, I don't think it is possible. Take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593580/how-to-extract-one-column-from-multiple-files-and-paste-into-one-file . Or think about specialized programming language.