# Extract column 'x' from multiple files, and transpose file name with 'x'

Tags: shell, unix, awk, find, cut

I am trying to extract column "m" from multiple txt files (file1.txt, file2.txt,,,etc) and transpose each column to a row in new file.

Below is `file1.txt`:

```
contig_1    contig_1    geneX       ctg1_886;ctg1_887;ctg1_888
contig_2    contig_2    geneY       ctg1_886;ctg1_887;ctg1_888
contig_3    contig_3    genesZ      ctg1_886;ctg1_887;ctg1_888
```

I would like to have a `summary.txt` file which looks like:

```
file1 geneX geneY geneZ
file2 geneA geneY
.
.
.
etc.
```

Total row numbers may vary between files. I tried using `awk` without success.

Comment: This will be rather easy in awk, using a custom output record separator and a rule when the FNR is 1.

Comment: Is "file1.txt" the first line of _file1.txt_?

Comment: I get inspired by these two posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593580/how-to-extract-one-column-from-multiple-files-and-paste-into-one-file http://superuser.com/questions/690116/using-awk-with-find-exec

Comment: No, file1.txt is not the 1st line of the file1.txt. le colname is only in the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following glenn jackmans advise from the comments, an GNU AWK solution would look like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} BEGINFILE{print FILENAME} {print $3} ENDFILE{ printf("\n")}'  file*.txt
```

And an awk solution could look like this (sorry only gnu awk for testing):

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} FNR==1 {printf("\n%s", FILENAME)} {print $3} END{printf("\n")} '
```

**Explanation**

There are several *special* patterns:

- `BEGIN`, its action is executed once at the beginning. Here the `ORS` ( output record separator) is set to space, the effect is that you get from each original row a new column, this *is* the transpose step
- the `END` action is executed once at the end
- the `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` actions are executed once at the beginning and end of the processing of each file. Here the `FILENAME` respectively a linefeed is printed.

Comment: Note that BEGINFILE and ENDFILE require GNU awk.

Comment: This does work. Would you please quickly comment the different part of the code. Also, my files are like file1-pattern.txt. The code above keeps the whole name, could I just grep the part file1, directly in the code. Otherwise, I could do it afterwards. Bests,

Comment: @user3037937 I added explanations. I do not know what you need for the filename, but you have the whole arsenal of awk string handling functions at your service, to extract substrings from `FILENAME` and print only that substring corresponding to `file1`.

Comment: @Lars Fisher, Thank you very much for the clarifications and tip for extractions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field separators are multiple spaces:

```
for f in file*.txt ; do 
    echo $f `tr -s ' ' < $f | cut -d ' ' -f 3`
done > summary.txt
```

If the data is `<tab>` separated:

```
for f in file*.txt ; do 
    echo $f `cut -f 3 $f`
done > summary.txt
```